# Where did "Spineless" come from?

Tags: etymology

A spineless person is said to be, "without moral force, resolution, or courage; feeble" -  http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/spineless. So they are cowardly. But where did that term come from? Are creatures without spines such as worms or squids inherently without courage?

Comment: A spineless person can't *stand up for himself*, nor can he *stand firm* or *hold his head up* and *keep his back straight*. He must *stoop* and *cower* or *quiver* and *tremble* like a bowl of jelly. Note that all the metaphors apply to a spineless **person**, because people are *supposed to have spines*; a person without a spine is degenerate, lacking.

Comment: It came in every language of the world.

Comment: Spineless creatures are not inherently timid ([example](http://cdn-www.cracked.com/articleimages/wong/gianthornet3.jpg))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Dan Bron's comment above suggests, there is a tradition (in English, at least) of associating such heroic virtues as standing tall, standing firm, and standing up for oneself (or for what is right) with having a backbone (that is, vertebrae or a spine).

Also traditionally, assuming the appropriate posture of a supplicant—whether on a battlefield or in a king's court or (metaphorically) in any other situation—involves bowing down or lying prostrate before the victor or superior person from whom the supplicant is seeking mercy or asking a favor.

It seems likely that someone long ago noticed that the posture of submission is one in which, physically, the spine plays very little role—and this insight, I imagine, encouraged the figurative relationship between spinelessness and lack of courage, fortitude, resolution, etc.

But this connection, I think, is strictly concerned with differences between perceived types of human beings—between those who metaphorically as well as in reality possess spines (and who, as a result, can stand upright on their own two feet) and those who metaphorically lack them (and who, as a result, cannot). I doubt that the figure of speech was influenced in any meaningful way by consideration of whether hornets, for example, are braver or more craven than field mice.